# What is this thing from the faucet shut off valve called?

Tags: plumbing

[image: thing from shut off valve]

I found this thing in my faucet shut off valve under the bathroom sink after I disconnected the faucet's hose from it. It is making my hot water flow much more slowly than I like, and I am wondering what it's called, what its purpose is, and if I can just remove it?

Comment: If that's affecting your flow noticeably then it must be pretty badly clogged. It's quite a coarse strainer and should have little impact on flow if clean.

Comment: couldn't you also call it an aerator? or is that a different part altogether?

Comment: The aerator is usually installed at the point of exit, though structurally there's little difference between the two.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a strainer, it will catch bits of debris that ends up in the pipes to prevent them from getting stuck in the valves making them leak.

it's best to rinse it out to remove the debris currently in it and put it back for that purpose, or replace it.

Comment: If you have hard water, it can also help to soak it in vinegar for a bit to dissolve any caked-on minerals.

Comment: I'd lean towards replacement given the look of that thing.  The seal is very degraded and it looks like it might do more harm than good as far as keeping debris out of the water.  And these tend to be pretty cheap, likely under a dollar in the US.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I was able to find a replacement for that by searching for "rubber washer strainer" and that fixes my issue.

Comment: Interestingly, the washer was so badly deformed that it was blocked by parts of the rubber rather than by any debris or mineral buildup